# creating trigger that executes after insert of update on remote database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create or replace a trigger that is executed after an insert of update to a remote table. I understand that you cannot do DDl over a database link, but I was wondering if there is any way around this. Maybe dynamic sql so that the DDL is interpreted as a string? or creating a synonym with the DBlink and calling the synonym instead of the table name.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Create or replace TRIGGER_NAME 
after update or insert on REMOTE_TABLE@DB_link
for each row...
```

Comment: What is an "insert ***of*** update"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a trigger to fire when the remote table is updated, that trigger would need to be created on the remote database.  If you actually have privileges to create a trigger on the remote database, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just log in to the remote server and execute the DDL.  You could use the DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT procedure to run DDL on the remote server (assuming you have the privileges)

```
DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT@remote_server( 
  'create or replace trigger trigger_name ' ||
  ' after update or insert on table_name ' ||
  ' for each row ' ||
  ...
);
```

I'm hard pressed to imagine why you'd want to do this rather than just connecting to the remote server directly...